# Uboot compilation issue on Zync7045 Xilinx

Tags: u-boot

I am compiling u-boot v2020.01 source code separately (petalinux not involved) for Xilinx Zync706 Board  on Ubuntu 18.04.06 LTS

Executed the below following command for compilation.

1. `export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/alpha/dmazyna/build/tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/gcc-cross-arm/usr/libexec/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/10.2.0/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-`
2. `make zynq_zc706_defconfig`
3. `make`

But during compilation I am facing compilation error.

> HOSTLD  tools/mkimage   HOSTCC  tools/fit_info.o   HOSTLD  tools/fit_info   HOSTCC  tools/fit_check_sign.o   HOSTLD  tools/fit_check_sign   HOSTCC  tools/spl_size_limit   LD      arch/arm/cpu/built-in.o /bin/sh: /home/alpha/dmazyna/build/tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/gcc-cross-arm/usr/libexec/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/10.2.0/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ar: No such file or directory scripts/Makefile.build:355: recipe for target 'arch/arm/cpu/built-in.o' failed make[1]: *** [arch/arm/cpu/built-in.o] Error 127 Makefile:1698: recipe for target 'arch/arm/cpu' failed make: *** [arch/arm/cpu] Error 2 root@alpha:/home/alpha/Desktop/u-boot-v2020.01#

How to resolve the error?